# Mock an overloaded virtual method from the base class

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, c++14

I'm trying to mock a virtual method from base class that implements some basic functionalities and is invoked in overload version in derived class.
What's important is that I'm using old gmock!

I have a following code:

```
class BaseFoo
{
public:
    virtual bool init()
    {
        std::cout << "Some basic functionality" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};

class Foo : public BaseFoo
{
public:
    bool init() override
    {
        if (!BaseFoo::init())
            return false;
            
        std::cout << "Some additional functionality" << std::endl;
        
        return true;
    }
};

class MockFoo : public Foo
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(BaseFoo::init, bool());
}

TEST(FooTests, InitTest)
{
    Foo f;
    bool result = false;
    
    EXPECT_CALL(f, BaseFoo::init).WillOnce(testing::Return(true));
    
    result = f.init();
    
    ASSERT_TRUE(result);
}
```

Obviously it doesn't work.
Errors I get are:

```
error: cannot define member function 'BaseFoo::init' within 'MockFoo'
     MOCK_METHOD0(BaseFoo::init, bool());
     ^
error: 'gmock_BaseFoo' has not been declared
     MOCK_METHOD0(BaseFoo::init, bool());
     ^
error: 'gmock0_BaseFoo' has not been declared
     MOCK_METHOD0(BaseFoo::init, bool());
     ^
error: conflicting return type specified for 'virtual testing::internal::MockSpec<bool()>& MockFoo::init()'
     MOCK_METHOD0(BaseFoo::init, bool());
     ^
error:   overriding 'virtual bool Foo::init()'
     bool init() override
     ^
error: 'gmock0_BaseFoo' has not been declared
     MOCK_METHOD0(BaseFoo::init, bool())
     ^
error: 'gmock0_BaseFoo' has not been declared
     MOCK_METHOD0(BaseFoo::init, bool());
     ^
error: 'Foo::gmock_BaseFoo' has not been declared
     EXPECT_CALL(f, BaseFoo::init).WillOnce(testing::Return(true));
     ^
```

My goal is to mock the base class method so its call could be expected in the test.
Is there any way to achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read the tag description carefully [tag:gmock]. Do you want to use the Groovy mocking framework?

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is impossible. Mocks work atop the standard concept of virtual functions (vtable etc.), a mock method (as declared by `MOCK_METHOD`) is just an override of an existing virtual function, and thus it can not do anything that you can not do with standard virtual functions.

And when you write `if (!BaseFoo::init())`, you explicitly say which function you want to call, this call goes directly to `BaseFoo` without virtualness and vtable jumping in, so you have no way to override it in a mock.

The only way to get it working is to change the implementation of `Foo` or `BaseFoo`, for this you have a multitude of options. In particular, if you really need to test subclass *separately* from base class, then this probably means that the two classes are not tied close enough, and so probably you should consider composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

It's the best I could come up with and It was sufficient in my case. I hope it'll be helpful.

```
class BaseFoo
{
public:
    virtual bool init()
    {
        std::cout << "Some basic functionality" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};

class Foo : public BaseFoo
{
public:
    bool init() override
    {
        if (!initBase()) // used wrapped base class method
            return false;
            
        std::cout << "Some additional functionality" << std::endl;
        
        return true;
    }

    bool initBase() // wrap base class method invocation
    {
        return BaseFoo::init();
    }
};

class MockFoo : public Foo
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(initBase, bool()); // mock wrapper
}

TEST(FooTests, InitTest)
{
    Foo f;
    bool result = false;
    
    // expect wrapper to be invoked
    EXPECT_CALL(f, initBase).WillOnce(testing::Return(true));
    
    result = f.init();
    
    ASSERT_TRUE(result);
}
```